# Cross Object Formula for standard picklist?

Tags: formula-field, cross-object

I am trying to build a cross object formulae on a custom object X from a standard object.

I am trying to use the formulae (Patient__r.Status)on a formulae field where status is a picklist field on the standard object. it shows me the error that

> Error: Field Status is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

How can I remove this error?

Comment: can you post your formula code here

Comment: @Santanu Boral Patient__r.Status

Comment: If you need to access a value from picklist,  use the following: `TEXT(Patient__r.Status)`

Comment: Thanks @Oleksiy: This solved my issue. I was able to replicate this on a formulae field and populate it on the custom object. Using this formulae field i am trying to write another validation : AND(ISCHANGED(Final_Result__c ), 
ISPICKVAL(Lead_Status__c, "Admitted")) where lead status is the formulae field which i had created, it gave me the error "Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text".    how can this be rectified

Comment: Ispickvalue is expecting picklist, not a formula field

Comment: N.B. `formulae` is plural of `formula`

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should be something like this -

AND(ISCHANGED(Final_Result__c ), Lead_Status__c = "Admitted")

Comment: you don't need `==` for comparison in formula, just a single `=`, in opposite to Apex

Comment: Apologies! Updated!